# Neuroph Studion Null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, neural-network

I looked for a lot of answers for this problem but all of them refered to a file error mine. My log shows the following stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle.getTypeEnumName(XPStyle.java:155)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle.getBorder(XPStyle.java:275)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel$XPBorderValue.getXPValue(WindowsLookAndFeel.java:2403)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel$XPValue.createValue(WindowsLookAndFeel.java:2357)
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getFromHashtable(UIDefaults.java:233)
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.get(UIDefaults.java:163)
    at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.get(MultiUIDefaults.java:64)
    at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getBorder(UIDefaults.java:481)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getBorder(UIManager.java:759)
    at javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.getBorder(TitledBorder.java:416)
    at javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.getBorderInsets(TitledBorder.java:349)
    at javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder.getBorderInsets(AbstractBorder.java:75)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getInsets(JComponent.java:1826)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.adjustSize(GroupLayout.java:1109)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.preferredLayoutSize(GroupLayout.java:879)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Container.java:1794)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Container.java:1778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1664)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:1115)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(GridBagLayout.java:916)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(GridBagLayout.java:2071)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(GridBagLayout.java:2031)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(GridBagLayout.java:812)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1508)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1497)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1693)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1628)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2748)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I created two input, one output neural network and data set, putted the data set on the drag and drop part on the top of the neural network interface and then clicked train. A notice pops up that says `null` and when I click null I get the error above.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)